# Linear programming. Find the maximum number of vertex disjoint paths in a directed graph.

Tags: graph-theory, optimization, linear-programming, integer-programming

How I can write like an objective function  subject to its corresponding restriccions  the next problem?

(max "...")

subject to ($\sum "..." - \sum "..."=0$ $\forall$ "...")

I have a directed graph and I would like to find the maximum number of paths that there are between two nodes (source and destination) without repeating nodes.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you aware of the adjacency matrix $A$ of a graph?  The $a_{ij}$ component of $A^n$ is the number of directed walks of length $n$ from node $i$ to node $j$.

Comment: yes. I know this matrix: a_ij= 1 if exists a path between i and j. 0 in other case.

Comment: so each path must use different nodes from every other path?

Comment: yes. it is so. but i don't know how i must write this

Comment: over what space do you intend to optimize?  the collection of vertex-disjoint paths between two nodes is a set which grows exponentially in size as the number of vertices increase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by considering the following oriented graph:

For every node $x$ of your graph, create nodes $x_1$ and $x_2$, with an arc from $x_1$ to $x_2$.

For every arc $(x,y)$ of your graph, create arcs $(x_2,y_1)$ and $(y_2,x_1)$ with a unit capacity. (You can delete arcs entering your source and leaving your destination, they are useless).

Your problem is now equivalent to finding a maximum flow (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_flow_problem) between your source and destination (the maximum flow equals the maximum number of disjoint paths, and each flow will travel through one of the paths). Linear formulations of this problem are well known, see for example http://theory.stanford.edu/~trevisan/cs261/lecture15.pdf (first link on Google).

Comment: This answer has been so useful for me. But, where did this idea come about?

Comment: Well, Section 5.5. of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_flow_problem explains how to get a maximum number of edge disjoint paths. If you want vertex disjoint paths, you have to "transform" each vertex into an edge an apply the same strategy.
Alternatively, you can put unit capacities on every edge and every node and compute the maximum flow "with vertex capacities". It is the approach described in section 5.6 on the Wikipedia link, but I think it is easier to understand with the transformation described above.